# Trying to understand the use of a '!' character

Tags: oracle, query

I stumbled upon this query that someone wrote and was curious as to what '!' was being used for here.

```
SELECT ACC9.JPM_CAT_ITEM_ID,                          !a.accomplishment
ACCE9.JPM_DESCR90,                             !b.descr
ACC9.JPM_DATE_6,                               !a.dt_issued
TO_CHAR(ACC9.JPM_DATE_6,'YYYYMMDD') &ISSUE_DT_STD,
ACC9.jpm_date_3,                               !Expire dt
C9.XLATLONGNAME
from PS_JPM_PROFILE A9,
PS_JPM_JP_ITEMS ACC9,
PSXLATITEM c9,
PS_JPM_CAT_ITEMS ACCE9
  WHERE A9.JPM_PROFILE_ID = ACC9.JPM_PROFILE_ID;
```

Comment: Most likely a comment in a tool which translates its own SQL syntax to actual SQL before executing it.

Comment: @BalazsPapp -  yeah, all those horrible table and field names have the smell of some sort of ORM or other machine-generate gunk all over them!

Comment: @BalazsPapp, Those aren't horrible names. I worked at a healthcare company once and had to populate the SLES table. I never learned what SLES was. I just wrote the code. I agree that the bang is probably a comment.